# Issue with Ivan Heckman's allSnap

Tags: windows-8-preview

For the longest time I have used Ivan Heckman's allSnap program to better manage Windows on my pc by making them easily snap together, instead of overlapping.

However on Windows 8 I cannot seem to get this to work. I suspect it has something to do with how Win8 boarders seem to have a transparent pixel around the outside of the window padding boarder, but overall I would love to get the snapping functionality back if it is at all possible.

It's very hard trying to find information about this online as all I find are posts talking about snapping Metro apps to the side of the screen in Desktop Mode.

Comment: I suspect W8 uses a different window manager, if so allsnap needs to be re-written, you never mentioned what other OS's you were using it on.

Comment: ... [allSnap](http://ivanheckman.com/allsnap/)'s support for Windows 7 is not even 100%: `v1.50 Beta
Can run 64 and 32 bit, doesn't?? crash in Windows 7`. Why do you expect it to work with Windows 8 **Preview**!?

Comment: @iglvzx I think its desire more than expectation.

Comment: karl, did you try compatibility mode?

Comment: I have previously used allSnap on WinVista (32bit) and Win7 (both 32bit and 64bit for Win7 without fault).

I have just tried changing the program to use Win7 compatibility, turned it off and on again, but still the problem persists. The windows just overlap each other as though allSnap isn't even running.

Comment: Upon further inspection: In Windows 8 32-bit Enterprise N RTM, I can only get two Windows Explorer windows to snap together if I am resizing them, not when I am moving them. So, if 'hooking' is the technique that this software uses, I am now also asking how to turn 'hooking' on for Windows Explorer.

Comment: Yeah, I love that app too.  Appears to work fine in Windows 8.1 though, have not noticed an issue yet.  Just have to ensure I run *both* the 32 and 64bit versions together.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [WindowSpace](http://www.ntwind.com/software/windowspace.html), it does more than Allsnap, and works with Windows 8.
Costs money, but its really cool and you can test it for free.

Answer (score 1):

SU won't let me select the question as being solved/answered myself, nor let me comment on the individual comment as I don't have 50 posts, but I just wanted to say that the answer provided by Tobias has worked. WindowsSpace provides a working alternative to the depreciated allSnap software.

Answer (score 1):

[AquaSnap](http://www.nurgo-software.com/pricing/aquasnap) comes with a free version and does the job wonderfully well on my Windows 8.

Answer (score -1):

I am unable to access a windows 8 machine currently, but I found what appears to be a version of this app in the windows 8 appstore.

http://www.windows8appstore.com/windowssoftware/allsnap-132/623058.html

Ivan's website lists 1.33 or 1.5beta as the newest versions, and the listing on the app store reads 1.32- perhaps an older version works?

I will test this as soon as I can, I also desire this functionality.

Comment: This appears more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Apologies, I'll be more careful in the future.

It turns out it does not function properly anyway.